# Add data to a multidimensional string array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following method:

```
public ArrayList<String> process() throws IOException{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    ArrayList<String> capture = new ArrayList<String>();

    Elements tableRows = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for(Element tr: tableRows){
        if(tr.text().contains(airline)){
            capture.add(tr.text());
            System.out.println(tr.text());
            }
        }

    return capture;
}
```

which when the println is run, outputs the text below

```
London-LHR Aer Lingus EI159 18 Feb 13:45 Arrived 13:34
Paris-CDG Aer Lingus EI523 18 Feb 13:55 Arrived 14:35
Rome Aer Lingus EI403 18 Feb 14:10 Arrived 13:56
Amsterdam Aer Lingus EI609 18 Feb 17:25 Arrived 17:14
```

and so on.

I want to be able to add the above data into a mulitdimensional array, like rows and columns, as I want to be able to sort by different columns: ie in ascending or descending arrival time etc.....

I'm new to java and learning as I go here and I'm unable to find anything online to help me.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you should do is create a class for each flight, and use different `Comparator`s to achieve the sorting you want

Comment: Not a class for each flight.  Just one class, and an instance of it for each flight.

Comment: Can someone explain how I do this? I'm new to Java and learning as I go

Comment: I agree. Use an Array of Objects instead of a multi-dim array. It will save you lots of trouble now and later.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: How and why would I use an instance of a new class for each flight?

Answer (score -1):

I thought so you have to create one class of Flight and then you can implement your own compare method, by implementing Comparator Interface in Java like

Psuedo Code for it you can change it according to your requirement

```
public class MyFlight implements Comparator<String>{


              @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.equals(o2) ? 0 : 1;
                }  
}
```

Comment: Comparator<String>? public int compare()? a comparator which returns 0 or 1? Your pseudo code is more confusing than helpful.